# string concat operator(||) throwing error in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to concat string columns in table with concat operator || and throwing error.

```
Here is the query: select "Bob"||'~'||"glad" from table

its throwing error as : ParseException - cannpt recognize input near '|' '"~"' '|' in expression specification
```

its works with concat function but not with concat operator.

```
select concat("bob","~","glad") from table - its working
```

I am using hive version 2.1 and could anyone tell me why this operator not working?

Thanks,Babu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive doesnt support concat operator `||`, its oracle syntax. Please use `concat` function to concat multiple values. You can use `concat_ws` to concat with a delimiter.
concat

```
select concat ('this','~','is','~','hello','~','world');
Output : this~is~hello~world
select concat_ws ('~','hello','world','is','not','enough');
Output : hello~world~is~not~enough
```

Comment: Hi Koushik, Thank you for your quick reply. I am using || in hive 3.x and its working. I am moving my code to hive 2.x version and facing this issue. I am passing this sql statement through shell script to execute and do you think its a problem with shell script?

Comment: hmm, interesting. Possible, can you pls see what is final SQL its generating ? And then fire the SQL in hive 2.x. If SQL works then shell has issue. if SQL doesnt work then see where is the issue - is it shell or sql.

Comment: Yes, I tried and looks like issue with SQL for the concatenate operator ||. All the documents says we can use || for concatenate but its throwing error while using it. Not sure what is the issue. When I change it to concat_ws, it works fine.

Comment: what is the exact version of your hive ? i tested on 2.1.1 and its working.

Comment: It is  hive 1.2.1000.2.6.1.40-4

Comment: so, pls use `concat` in lower versions. Thx for confirming that.